# golang type assertion on map is panicking

Tags: go

Type assertion on a map doesn't work, is this the right way to do it?

**Just to elaborate, my goal is to return a map with dynamic types. this example is just for demonstration.**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main()  {
    m := hello().(map[string]int)
    fmt.Println(m)
}

func hello() interface{} {
    return map[string]interface{} {
        "foo": 2,
        "bar": 3,
    }
}
```

it panics

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {},
>   not map[string]int

Comment: Whats the question? A `map[string]interface{}` isn't a `map[string]int` so the type assertion fails.

Comment: am i right to suppose that the map has key as string and value as int? type assertion with types other then map works with those assumptions

Comment: You can't do a type assertion to an incompatible type. You must manually convert it instead.

Answer (score 0):

return the appropriate type

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main()  {
    m := hello().(map[string]int)
    fmt.Println(m)
}

func hello() interface{} {
    return map[string]int{
        "foo": 2,
        "bar": 3,
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not at a liberty to return a static type, a map could hold any type as key and any type as value. right now for the sake of demonstration i have considered the values as interface. am i doing this right?

Comment: so you need map[interface{}]interface{}

Comment: yeah, if i can figure out map[string]interface{} for now i will see the second part later.

Comment: `Just to elaborate, my goal is to return a map with dynamic types` there is no such thing in go. You can however use interface{} to mixin multiple types.

Comment: i am using reflection to achieve that to some level. With other types it works but with maps i am getting this error.

Answer (score -1):

To answer my own question, **assertion works on map values**

a few examples

```
package main

import "fmt"

type person struct {
    name string
}

func main()  {
    m := example1().(map[string]interface{})

    fmt.Println(m["foo"].(int))

    m2 := example2().(map[string]interface{})

    fmt.Println(m2["foo"].(person).name)

}

func example1() interface{} {
    return map[string]interface{} {
        "foo": 2,
        "bar": 3,
    }
}

func example2() interface{} {
    m := make(map[string]interface{})

    m["foo"] = person{"Name is foo!"}
    m["bar"] = person{"Name is bar!"}

    return m
}
```